# CRA, Node.js, nginx in Docker?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, create-react-app

I'm starting off a new project. I currently have a strucute like this, from root folder:

`/app (CRA frontend app)
/server (Node.js Express app)
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml`

My requirements is the following:

**Development**

- Fire up Docker that creates necessary container(s)
- Hot reloading for frontend React app (using CRA)
- Node.js server that can serve my React app with SSR (automatically updated when editing)
- Accessible via http://localhost:3000

**Production**

- Potentially fire up Docker that creates necessary container(s)
- Creates production ready version of React app
- Creates production ready version of Express app
- Accessible via port 80

Where I am right now is somewhere between everything. I don't know how to setup Docker the right way in order to make this whole thing work, and I don't really know how to structure my React app vs the Express app while developing. The Production part seems to be easier as soon as I know how to structure the Development part... + Nginx as a proxy for the Express app?

I'm currently building a Docker container which fires up a container where hot reloading is working etc, but I don't know how to setup the Express part so they work nicely together...?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very vague. It would be better to break down your project into more direct questions. Anyway, I don't think running your dev setup in Docker is recommended (unless you know what you're doing) instead it would be better to build you app normally with CRA. Then deploy in Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Very broad question. Perhaps better to break it down into more direct questions. Anyway, I don't think running your dev setup in Docker is ideal. Instead build your app normally with CRA. Then deploy in Docker.

In my own projects, I have a docker container running a node server which serves the react app using SSR.

Here is the docker part. Note that your `package.json` should have a script named `start:prod` for this to work. That script then starts your app in production.

```
// --- Dockerfile
# Pulled from docker hub and has everything
# needed to run a node project
FROM node:alpine

ENV PORT 3000

# Navigate (cd) to the app folder in the docker container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy all package.json / package-lock.json etc. to the root folder
# Executed on build: docker build .
COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm i

# copy entire project into docker container
COPY . .

# build front-end with react build scripts and store them in the build folder
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Here's the express server that will start the server.

```
// -- server.js

import express from "express";
import router from "./controller/index";

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

// Tell the app to use the routes above
app.use(router);

// start the app
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`express running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Here is the `controller/index.js` file you'll need to start up

```
// -- controller/index.js
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import serverRenderer from '../middleware/renderer';

const router = express.Router();

// root (/) should always serve our server rendered page
router.use('^/$', serverRenderer());

// other static resources should just be served as they are
router.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build'),
    { maxAge: '30d' },
));

export default router;
```

And finally the renderer which renders the app on the server.

```
// -- renderer.js

import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import App from "../../src/App";

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

export default () => (req, res) => {
    // point to html file created by CRA's build tool
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "build", "index.html");
    fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (error, htmlData) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("error", error);
            return response.status(404).end();
        }

        // render the app as string
        const html = renderToString(<App />);

        // inject rendered app into final html and send
        return res.send(
            htmlData
                .replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`)
        );
    })
}
```

You will need `bootstrap.js` to inject support for certain packages.

```
// -- bootstrap.js
require('ignore-styles');
require('url-loader');
require('file-loader');
require('babel-register')({
    ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react-app'],
    plugins: [
        'syntax-dynamic-import',
        'dynamic-import-node'
    ]
});

require("./index");
```

You can find the details of it all here: 
https://blog.mytoori.com/react-served-by-express-running-in-docker-container

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try! Sorry for my vague question :) Will let you know if this is working for me.

Comment: i am getting error const html = renderToString(<App />) syntax error unexpected token

Comment: do we need babel core or babel cli, when i check for the error it is showing that any idea on this

Comment: does your command should be npm run prod:start or  npm run build ?

Comment: in index.js file of /server folder should we auto require the bootstrap.js  ??

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, I suspect you might be using server/index.js when you should be importing bootstrap.js. My best recommendation is to check the original source code on github: https://github.com/Giwan/fe-docker-dynamic-be/blob/ssr/server/server.js (note that the file names are slightly different there)